# Где хранить данные о покупках

Tags: java, android

Как оптимальнее организовать хранение данных о покупке, например, пользователь купил 2 ед. товара. Приложение закрыл, открыл через неделю, воспользовался товаром. Где все это хранится?
Сервера своего нет.

Comment: в локальной минибазе, не знаю как это точно работает на андроид, а так, в папке приложения создать файлик, который будет в формате json, например, хранить необходимую информацию по объекту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без хранения на сервере не обойтись, если у вас покупают что-то не один раз и вам не хочется вручную искать данные транзакции и вручную же юзеру её на телефон восстанавливать после смены юзером телефона.

Локально хранимые данные могут быть утерены вместе с девайсом или при удалении данных самим юзером или к-л программами очистки памяти на его девайсе.

Самое правильное (а также долгое и сложное) решение - хранить данные на своём сервере.

Самое простое - использовать готовые решения для удалённого хранения данных. Например `Firebase` от гугла. Однако, как и со всем остальным, надо быть большим спецом, чтобы сделать всё правильно и не выйти за ограничения бесплатного использования.

Если же для вас не страшна потеря юзером данных, то можно просто в префы, локальную БД или даже в файл на девайсе всё это записать.

Comment: Если это бессрочные покупки, то можно через biling-api можно получить список покупок юзера и без сервака. Другое дело, если это используемые продукты.

Comment: @Suvitruf, именно так) Я на это в первом абзаце и намекал) Однако, кажется, у ТС как раз 2-ой вариант.